# How to generate dynamic sitemap in next js with sitemap package?

Tags: xml, next.js, sitemap, parse-server

I'm using next js and back4app for my web application. I came across the `sitemap` library to write a sitemap, but I am not able to create a dynamic site map at all. I am not able to run any api calls or cloud code, I have a specific function which will return all the routes so that I can pipe them. Here is my sample code below:

```js
import { SitemapStream, streamToPromise } from "sitemap";
const {Readable} = require("stream");
import cacheData from 'memory-cache';
import { initializeParse } from '@parse/react-ssr';



initializeParse( 
    'https://parseapi.back4app.com',
    '********************',
    '*********************'
  );

const sitemap = async (req,res) => {

    try{
        const links = [
            { url: "/blogggy", changefreq: "daily", priority: 0.3 },
        ];
        const userParams = {
            authKey: "***********************"
        }


         Parse.Cloud.run("getAllRoutes",userParams).then(response =>{
             response.map((handle) => {
                 links.push({
                   url: `/${handle}`,
                   changefreq: "daily",
                   priority: 0.9,
                 });
               })
         }).catch(e =>{
             res.send(JSON.stringify(e));
         })
        

        const pages = ["/explore"];
        pages.map((url) => {
          links.push({
            url,
            changefreq: "daily",
            priority: 0.9,
          });
        });
        
        const stream = new SitemapStream({hostname: `https://${req.headers.host}`}) ; 
        
        res.writeHead(200,{
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
        });
        
        const xmlString = await streamToPromise(
            Readable.from(links).pipe(stream)
        ).then((data) => data.toString());
        
        res.end(xmlString);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
};


export default sitemap
```

I also tried getServerSideProps but it didn't work. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I see you are not await the Parse.Cloud.run() to complete. So you are trying to responde the links before they were actually pushed. That's for sure a problem but I am not sure if that's the only one. Would mind to share any logs or detail that is the output you have and what exactly is not working with your code?

Comment: I already tried the await method, but it didn't work. The sitemap becomes an empty string with the output `{}` whenever I use async, and since its an XML file, I'm not able to produce any console logs to the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I'm not sure if that's the only problem with your code, but try to rewrite the cloud code function call to something like this:

```js
let response;
try {
  response = await Parse.Cloud.run("getAllRoutes",userParams);
}
catch (e) {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(e));
  return;
}
response.map((handle) => {
  links.push({
    url: `/${handle}`,
    changefreq: "daily",
    priority: 0.9,
  });
});
```

Comment: let me try this and get back to you !